# GCP - Python: Is it possible to rename a file without using the os module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the google cloud functions, I need to delete and rename files but using the `os` module and any module which is similar to it, will cause problems on Google cloud platform. I don't have the exact error message now, but I now that from a previous experience.

I'm thinking to rewrite the file, because reading/writing files is working. Is there any better option that can be safely used in Google cloud functions?

So basically if you do upload a text file to the google cloud function and then do `os.rename("foo.txtr,bar.txt")`, you get an error [like this one](https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues/1739).

Comment: try: shutil.move()

Comment: @Aymen okay will do

Comment: Your question needs specific details. Renaming a file can mean many things in the cloud. The solution depends on what you are renaming and where it is stored.

Comment: @Aymen your suggestion works, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: @JohnHanley  `shutil.move()` works, hopefully, Aymen posts it as an answer so that I can give him an upvote and accept his answer, he rightfully deserves to have that. As for how to reproduce the issue, try to upload a text file to a google cloud function written in python and then do `os.rename("foo.text","bar.text") you'll get an error which is similar to [this](https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues/1739). Not sure if the exact same error but very similar. In any case, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the details I requested. It is important that your question clearly defined a problem so that future readers will know that the answer applies to their problem Please start by reading this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then this one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JohnHanley Alright sir, I moved the details from the comment section to the question, I won't do any more than that for two reasons: one the issue is solved, and two, I won't cause an error in a cloud function running in production on purpose just to paste the error message here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instruction instead:

```
shutil.move()
```